# socket.io undefined after trying to pass it from a module

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I have two modules, main module `server.js` and `socket.js`.

In `socket.js` I have a public empty var `io` which I'm trying to assign socket.io and use later on to handle the sockets,
however to initialize socket.io, I have to do it from `server.js` module, since I have to do it with expressjs.

Here's my attempt at making this work, I'm pretty sure I'm missing something small:

server.js
`

```
var socket = require('socket.js'); //the module
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
socket.io = require('socket.io')(server);`
```

socket.js

```
var io;
module.exports.io = io;
module.exports.handleSockets = somefunction();
```

`handleSockets` is called later on when it's actually needed, and `io` of `server.js` actually initializes and runs fine, though it's undefined in `socket.js`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things:
first of all you should require your file as

```
var socket = require('./socket.js'); //the module
```

since it is another file in the same folder.

And io variable (in socket.js) is never initialized, so it is normal it's undefined.

I think you should just initialize it in server.js and pass it on to socket.js. Something like this:

server.js

```
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var socket = require('./socket.js')(io);
```

socket.js

```
function somefunction(io) { ... }
module.exports = somefunction;
```

Comment: I've tried initializing it in through `var io = require('socket.io')` but that just ends up creating a new instance. I'm pretty sure I can't use `module.exports` from the main module.

Comment: i have edited my answer, because code looks terrible in the comments